# Webdriver cannot start the tests 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService' after java upgrades

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I was playing around with appium and some other testing tools, in order to do so, I changed my java version to the most recent ones.
All my current versions are:
**Java 8, JDK 13, npm 6.13.4, protractor 5.4.2, chrome driver 79**

After checking the tools, I moved back to my main project in protractor, I tried to run my scenarios and  webdriver was trying to access the wrong path to find the drivers.
Then I removed the appium installation from my machine and deleted older versions of java as well.

The result was this error:

```
[17:20:18] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:20:18] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[17:20:18] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'EEW00351', ip: 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'

Driver info: driver.version: unknown

[17:20:18] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'EEW00351', ip: 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:53:33) at Runner.createBrowser     
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at c:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch 
(C:\Users\alexandre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    [17:20:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I tried to solve this removing all older version of java, updating protractor version, upgrading webdriver-manager... removing everything and adding all again...

None of those helped.

the webdriver even "start" but nothing happens.. I only get that error showed above

```
17:44:14.118 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--start-maximized"
    ]
  },
  "count": 1
}
17:44:19.102 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Any idea of what I can do to fix this? I didn't change anything in the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So.. after few hours of burning some energy...
I deleted everything... installed node again

Created an env variable with the company's proxy (this solves the webdriver timout issue, even if you send the proxy via command line, it doesnt work, so create the env variable)

Installed protractor again, updated webdriver-manager again.

forced an upgrade in chrome, the company controls the version, I had 78 (driver was 78 as well) before, and now I have 79.

and it is working